# Map enum values to corresponding types with templates at compile time?

Tags: c++, reflection, c++20, typeid

I have an idea of mapping enum values to corresponding data types, at compile time with templates. How can i do this?

e.g.

```cpp
enum DataType {
  UNSINGED_INT; // uint32_t
  INT; // int32_t
  UNSIGNED_CHAR; // uint8_t
  CHAR; // int8_t
}

auto type = MapToDataType<DataType::UNSIGNED_CHAR>; // type will be uint8_t in this case
```

Comment: do you mean `using type = ....` ?

Comment: 1. Are you sure you really need to do this? 2. There may well be an existing library which solves the problem you are actually facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the enum class. Use class to avoid namespace pollution.

```
#include <cstdint>

enum class DataType {
    UNSIGNED_CHAR,
    UNSIGNED_INT,
    CHAR,
    INT
};
```

Specialize a template for each enum entry:

```
template <DataType> struct MapToDataType_t;
template <> struct MapToDataType_t<DataType::UNSIGNED_CHAR> { using type = std::uint8_t; };
template <> struct MapToDataType_t<DataType::UNSIGNED_INT>  { using type = std::unit32_t; };
template <> struct MapToDataType_t<DataType::CHAR>          { using type = std::int8_t; };
template <> struct MapToDataType_t<DataType::INT>           { using type = std::int32_t; };
```

Alias each type:

```
template <DataType T>
using MapToDataType = typename MapToDataType_t<T>::type;
```

Answer (score 4):

If your `enum` contains a sequence of values convertible to `int`, without holes, and starting from zero (as in your example), you can use a `std::tuple` as type map and `std::tuple_element` to extract the desired type.

So, write an helper struct as follows

```
template <DataType dt>
struct MapToDataType_helper
 {
   using type = typename std::tuple_element<
     static_cast<std::size_t>(dt),
     std::tuple<std::uint32_t,
                std::int32_t,
                std::uint8_t,
                std::int8_t>
                   >::type;
 };
```

your map is a simple template using

```
template <DataType dt>
using MapToDataType = typename MapToDataType_helper<dt>::type;
```

For example, you can verify that

```
static_assert( std::is_same_v<MapToDataType<DataType::UNSIGNED_CHAR>,
                              std::uint8_t> );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
template <DataType> struct MapToDataTypeHelper {};
template <> struct MapToDataTypeHelper<INT> {using type = int;};
template <> struct MapToDataTypeHelper<UNSIGNED_INT> {using type = unsigned int;};
// ...

template <DataType X> using MapToDataType = typename MapToDataTypeHelper<X>::type;
```

```
MapToDataType<INT> x; // int x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Some tag types and values to carry compile time values and types around:

```
template<auto x>
using constant_t = std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(x)>, x>;
template<auto x>
constexpr constant_t<x> constant{};
template<class T>
struct tag_t{using type=T;};
template<class T>
constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};

template<class X>
constexpr void type_map( X ) {}

template<auto X>
using get_type = typename decltype(type_map(constant<X>))::type;
```

Ok, the machinery is done.

Now just add these:

```
    inline auto type_map( constant_t<DataType::UNSIGNED_INT> ) { return tag<std::uint32_t>; }
    inline auto type_map( constant_t<DataType::INT> ) { return tag<std::int32_t>; }
    inline auto type_map( constant_t<DataType::UNSIGNED_CHAR> ) { return tag<std::uint8_t>; }
    inline auto type_map( constant_t<DataType::CHAR> ) { return tag<std::int8_t>; }
```

and it works.

Supporting other enums is just a matter of adding `type_map` overloads into the namespace of the `enum` in question.

A macro

```
#define TYPE_MAP(FROM,...) \
  inline auto type_map( constant_t<FROM> ) { return tag<__VA_ARGS__>; }
```

can make it less verbose.

`get_type` now works uniformly on any enum with the same machinery set up on it.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/qaohWfvfe).